# Will a modern AC automatically switch between cooling and heating?

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

Say I set the temp to 23C on a hot day but the weather turns cold eventually. Will it detect later that autumn came and heating is needed? I'm talking about a Panasonic inverter AC.

Comment: Is there an "AUTO" mode on your AC unit or remote? What is your specific model? Some quick searching about "Panasonic inverter AC" revealed that an automatic mode definitely exists for some models.

Comment: Yes there is an auto mode, it's an etherea 2.5KW model. The exact number varies by country afaik. Is the auto mode so auto that it determines the heat transfer direction?

Comment: Have you consulted the owners manual?